# Selenium and DevTools - implementing getDevTools() in custom Browser.driver() class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to use DevTools with Selenium 4.8, but I'm running into problems related to my how Selenium framework is set up.

If I create a new ChromeDriver instance in my test, I'm able to instantiate DevTools like this:

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
DevTools devTool = driver.getDevTools();
devTool.createSession();
```

However, my tests use a Browser->WebDriverr implementation class, in which WebDriver is returned with different parameters, depending on what I need:

Browser.class:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import <LOCAL ADDRESS REMOVED>.selenium.config.BrowserConfig;
import <LOCAL ADDRESS REMOVED>.selenium.config.SeleniumOptions;
import <LOCAL ADDRESS REMOVED>.selenium.driver.ExtendedWebDriver;
import <LOCAL ADDRESS REMOVED>.selenium.driver.WebDriverFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.LocalFileDetector;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.InvalidParameterException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static java.lang.String.format;

@Slf4j
public class Browser {
    public static final int DEFAULT_IMPLICIT_WAIT = 0;
    public static final int DEFAULT_SCRIPT_TIMEOUT = 20;
    public static final int DEFAULT_WAIT_TIMEOUT = 30;
    public static long globalWaitTimeout;
    private static boolean useRemoteDriver = false;
    private static SeleniumOptions.WebAppTeknologi webAppTeknologi = SeleniumOptions.WebAppTeknologi.INGEN;
    private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver=new ThreadLocal<>();
    private static ThreadLocal<ExtendedWebDriver> extendedDriver=new ThreadLocal<>();
    private static ThreadLocal<JavascriptExecutor> jsExecutor=new ThreadLocal<>();
    private static ThreadLocal<WebDriverWait> standardWait=new ThreadLocal<>();

    private Browser() {}

    public static void init(BrowserConfig browserConfig, List<String> chromeOptionsParameters) throws MalformedURLException {
        Browser.webAppTeknologi = browserConfig.getWebAppTeknologi();
        String seleniumGridUrl = browserConfig.getSeleniumGridAdresse();
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(seleniumGridUrl)) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                try {
                    opprettEksternBrowser(browserConfig.getNettleserType(), new URL(seleniumGridUrl));
                    break;
                }
                catch (org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException unreachableBrowserException) {
                    log.debug(String.format("Klarte ikke starte browser mot %s på forsøk nr %s. Venter 10 s",seleniumGridUrl,i));
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            opprettLokalBrowser(browserConfig.getNettleserType(), chromeOptionsParameters);
        }

        setBrowserTimeouts(DEFAULT_SCRIPT_TIMEOUT, DEFAULT_IMPLICIT_WAIT, DEFAULT_WAIT_TIMEOUT);
    }

    private static void opprettLokalBrowser(SeleniumOptions.NettleserType browser, List<String> chromeOptionsParameters) {
        switch (browser) {
            case CHROME:
                final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

                if (chromeOptionsParameters != null) {
                    for (String parameter : chromeOptionsParameters) {
                        chromeOptions.addArguments(parameter);
                    }
                }

                driver.set(new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions));
                log.debug("Chrome valgt som ønsket nettleser.");
                break;
            case CHROME_HEADLESS:
                final ChromeOptions chromeOptions2 = new ChromeOptions();
                chromeOptions2.setHeadless(true);
                driver.set(new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions2));
                log.debug("Chrome Headless valgt som ønsket nettleser.");
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidArgumentException(format("Nettleser '%s' ikke implementert i rammeverk", browser.name()));
        }
    }

    private static void opprettEksternBrowser(SeleniumOptions.NettleserType browser, URL seleniumGridUrl) {
        useRemoteDriver = true;
        RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver;
        switch (browser) {
            case CHROME:
                final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(seleniumGridUrl, chromeOptions);
                log.debug("Remote (Chrome) valgt som ønsket nettleser.");
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidParameterException(format("Nettleser %s for selenium grid ikke implementert i rammeverk", browser.name()));
        }
        remoteWebDriver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector()); // For filopplasting fra lokal-path
        driver.set(remoteWebDriver);
    }

    public static void setBrowserTimeouts(int scriptTimeout, int implicitWait, int waitTimeout) {
        if (driver == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Browser.init() må kjøres før man kan kalle driver-instansen");
        }
        driver.get().manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(scriptTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(implicitWait, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        globalWaitTimeout = (long) waitTimeout;
        standardWait.set(new WebDriverWait(driver.get(), Duration.ofSeconds(waitTimeout)));
    }

    public static WebDriver vanillaDriver() {
        if (driver.get() == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Browser.init() må kjøres før man kan kalle driver-instansen");
        }
        return driver.get();
    }

    public static ExtendedWebDriver extendedDriver() {
        if (extendedDriver.get() != null) {
            return extendedDriver.get();
        }
        if (getWebAppType().equals(SeleniumOptions.WebAppTeknologi.INGEN)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Ingen WebAppTeknologi satt, bruk vanillaDriver() eller sett WebAppTeknologi");
        }
        extendedDriver.set(WebDriverFactory.getExtendedWebDriver(vanillaDriver(), webAppTeknologi));
        return extendedDriver.get();
    }

    public static JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor() {
        if (jsExecutor.get() == null) {
            WebDriver jsDriver = vanillaDriver();
            jsExecutor.set((JavascriptExecutor) jsDriver);
        }
        return jsExecutor.get();
    }

    public static WebDriverWait Wait() {
        if (standardWait.get() == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("StandardWait er ikke satt");
        }
        return standardWait.get();
    }

    public static WebDriverWait Wait(long timeOutInSeconds) {
        return new WebDriverWait(vanillaDriver(), Duration.ofSeconds(timeOutInSeconds));
    }

    public static boolean isRemoteDriver() {
        return useRemoteDriver;
    }

    public static SeleniumOptions.WebAppTeknologi getWebAppType() {
        return webAppTeknologi;
    }

}
```

Lots of messy stuff in there, but I cannot clean it up at the moment.

So, my question is: How do I implement a getDevTools() method in the above class? So that I can use something like:

```
WebDriver extendedDriver = Browser.ExtendedDriver();
DevTools devTool = extendedDriver.getDevTools();
devTool.createSession();
```